# Batch to delete profile folder on network pc after local profile reset

Tags: batch-file, directory, user-profile

I've recently created a batchfile to reset a local W7 profile on a network pc.
This works as it is supposed to, but sometimes the profile folder isn't removed.
Therefore I would like to verify and delete any profile folder beginning with the user's logon.

I'm trying to do this with the following code:

```
for /f %%i in ('ping -n 1 %workstation% ^| find /c "(0%% loss)"') do SET PINGRESULT=%%i
    If %PINGRESULT%==1 (
        If exist \\%workstation%\c$\users\%usr%* (
            echo Profile folder found, trying to delete >> log.txt
            FOR /D /R %%X IN (\\%workstation%\c$\users\%usr%*) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
        ) ELSE (
            echo Profile Folder not found >> log.txt
        )   
            )
```

The folder is found, but it isn't removed. And I'm not getting any error message.

Comment: After messing around I noticed that:
FOR /D %%X IN (\\%workstation%\c$\users\%usr%*) DO RD /S /Q %%X
seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP wrote in a comment:

> After messing around I noticed that:
>
> ```
> FOR /D %%X IN (\\%workstation%\c$\users\%usr%*) DO RD /S /Q %%X
> ```
>
> seems to do the trick.

Comment: ([Question answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)